# Will modern grenade explode if it strapped into a remote detonated explosive of same size or larger?

Tags: science-based, explosions

Imagine you are give the power to create/summon explosive munitions of any type (with detonators of course) however you are limited on how much you can summon at any moment (1 per 5 seconds and a maximum of 5 at any given moment or type of explosives you have).

Now since I can only summon 2 types of explosives, a grenade (Pineapple) and a c4 (1kg) with remote detonator. Now since I have limitations and I need a bigger bang for my buck but at the same time much more destructive to fleshy bits regardless if they are armored or not it was decided that making a satchel charge (Correct me if I am wrong) of 4 grenades surrounding the c4.

Will the grenades explode when the c4 detonates?

Are there any combinations of the 2 that will give me a bigger bang for my buck while still achieving the objective of showering anyone surrounding it with shrapnel?

Comment: Why not summon 5 C4, mash them together (plastic explosive is, well, plastic) and stick a lot of ball-bearings or small metal trash in the outer layer?

Comment: Yeah i could do that with preparation.. but what if i need to make it on the fly or on spot?

Comment: OK, what does it have to do with building new fictional worlds? How is this supposed to be world-changing information?

Comment: put it in a medieval perspective you get a world changing information i just want to make what i had in mind deadly... i can pretty much demolish a mounted charge with right timing... This is in conjunction with matter-space compression powers i posted while ago

Do i need to put my whole fiction world here to make sense about what i posted?

Comment: Probably worth noting that - even if they do go off - 4 grenades won't make a huge difference to the explosive power of the C4. A more likely use could be to disassemble the grenade and use it do detonate the C4 (via a peice of string, etc - you don't want to be next to it when it goes off!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the purposes of each type of munition.  The reason they both exist in the real world is because they are tools for different purposes. Grenades are for killing personnel at a radius of 15 feet with an effective radius of 30 feet. Meaning that the shrapnel is fatal at 15 and likely to injure you at 30. C4 is similar.to th explosive charge inside grenades but the killing force is amplified by the increased pressure inside the combustion chamber and then carried by the fragmentation. Naked c4 will just create a shockwave that will dissipate quickly with distance.
So the answer to your question is: It depends.
For example if i was magical i would summon a grenade among enemies if they where bunched up. In an enclosed room such as a bedroom i would create structural damage by placing c4 in the rafters or the floor. Outdoors i would summon c4 underground.
Long story short it is the solids that ride the concussion wave that give you the "greatest bang for the buck"
By the way, when I was in the Marines I got to witness grenade explosions and they are alot stronger and scarier than anything I've seen in movies.  There is very little open flame and the concussion is very strong. I always laugh when people in movies survive a grenade and can talk and hear normally

Answer (score 2):

You should recognize that strapping C4 to a grenade is actually the means of disposing of a "dud" grenade. A Canadian C-13 grenade has @ 500 grams of C4 inside it already (to shatter the casing and spray shrapnel through the air), and most other NATO and Russian grenades are built in a similar manner (perhaps using different explosives inside, like Semtex rather than C4).

The blast of the exploding external charge isn't so much to cause the internal charge of the grenade to detonate when disposing of a dud, but rather th shatter the grenade and distribute the parts over a wide area so they cannot explode or be reassembled into a fresh IED or similar. IF you are lucky, the detonation charge inside the grenade might be triggered by the external explosion and the grenade "blows up", but since it is already being consumed by the external charge this would not be a noticeable effect (unless you are filming with a really high speed camera).

As a weapon, this would have less effect than you might imagine. The powerful shockwave of the C4 explosion would dissipate rapidly in the atmosphere (unless you are silly enough to do this in an enclosed space) and the spread of shrapnel from the grenade itself is not going to be symmetrical, but the metallic parts of the grenade will be flung in a more random pattern by the external explosion.

Weapons are designed for a purpose, and generally don't work as well when you try to use them for something they were not designed to do.